# Error: Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip. Binance pay api PHP

Tags: php, api, binance

Hola recientemente encontre este pequeño proyecto en GITHUB https://github.com/Monyancha/binance-pay-api-php-laravel-curl
El cual permite consumir la api de binance para realizar pagos por medio de su plataforma, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar lo unico que me aparece es el siguiente error:
`string(125) "{"status":"FAIL","code":"400004","errorMessage":"Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip: 186.47.182.133"}"`

El codigo usado es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    // Generate nonce string
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $nonce = '';
    for($i=1; $i <= 32; $i++)
    {
        $pos = mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1);
        $char = $chars[$pos];
        $nonce .= $char;
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    // Request body
     $request = array(
       "env" => array(
             "terminalType" => "APP" 
          ), 
       "merchantTradeNo" => mt_rand(982538,9825382937292), 
       "orderAmount" => 25.17, 
       "currency" => "BUSD", 
       "goods" => array(
                "goodsType" => "01", 
                "goodsCategory" => "D000", 
                "referenceGoodsId" => "7876763A3B", 
                "goodsName" => "Ice Cream", 
                "goodsDetail" => "Greentea ice cream cone" 
             ) 
    ); 
 
    $json_request = json_encode($request);
    $payload = $timestamp."\n".$nonce."\n".$json_request."\n";
    $binance_pay_key = "mi-pay-key";
    $binance_pay_secret = "mi-secret-key";
    $signature = strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA512',$payload,$binance_pay_secret));
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    $headers[] = "BinancePay-Timestamp: $timestamp";
    $headers[] = "BinancePay-Nonce: $nonce";
    $headers[] = "BinancePay-Certificate-SN: $binance_pay_key";
    $headers[] = "BinancePay-Signature: $signature";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bpay.binanceapi.com/binancepay/openapi/v2/order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_request);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }
    curl_close ($ch);

    var_dump($result);
    
    //Redirect user to the payment page

?>
```

No entiendo mucho de apis, por lo que me quede sin de cual podria ser el problema.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra es por que: no estas utilizando una clave unica para tu cuenta

debes cambiar estas lineas:

```php
    $binance_pay_key = "mi-pay-key";
    $binance_pay_secret = "mi-secret-key";
```

Entre las comillas debes escribir tus claves unicas.
Para generar dichas claves entra con tu cuenta de vendedor a https://www.binance.com/es y generas las claves

Answer (score 0):

Debes de asegurarte que en la api que creas en binance tener habilitado "Enable Spot & Margin Trading" y tu ip debe de estar en "Restrict access to trusted IPs only (Recommended)"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]